# Converting the host byte order to network byte order sometimes results in odd results

Tags: java, android, c++, sockets, networking

I am currently writing a server in c++ which is used by android clients. Basically I use googles protocol buffers for data transmission, before sending a protobuf package I send the package size in network byte order. Here is my function to send one package:

```
bool Client::sendOnePackage(const std::string & data) {
    int32_t packageSize = data.length();
    packageSize = htonl(packageSize);

    char packageSizeBuffer[sizeof (int32_t)];
    memcpy(packageSizeBuffer, &packageSize, sizeof (int32_t));

    if (send(con.sockfd, packageSizeBuffer, sizeof (int32_t), 0) == sizeof (int32_t)) {
        if (send(con.sockfd, data.c_str(), packageSize, 0) == packageSize) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

and the android part will then take care of the package converting the sent integer to the host byte order using:

```
int answerLength = ByteBuffer.wrap(answerLengthData).getInt();
```

The problem now: When I send a package Size of 8 over the wire, it works just fine, android recieves the byte array 0,0,0,8 (always 4 bytes). But when I send the value 6 over the wire, android receives the odd byte array 0,114,0,0 which results in an oddly large package size (7471104).

Am I missing something here? If you need further informations or more code, please ask for it, ill post it then.

Comment: Unrelated to this problem, but there's no need for the temporary character buffer, just use the integer variable directly. E.g. `send(con.sockfd, reinterpret_cast<char*>(&packageSize), sizeof(packageSize), 0)`

Comment: Your variable `packageSize` gets converted to network byte order and then you try to use it as a length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You overwrite value of `packageSize` with result of `htonl()`:

```
packageSize = htonl(packageSize);
```

And then you use it as package size passed to `send()`:

```
send(con.sockfd, data.c_str(), packageSize, 0)
```

Save conerted value in different variable. And don't use temporary char buffer:

```
bool Client::sendOnePackage(const std::string & data) {
    int32_t packageSize = data.length();
    int32_t conv_size = htonl(packageSize);

    if (send(con.sockfd, reinterpret_cast<char*>(&conv_size), sizeof (int32_t), 0) == sizeof (int32_t)) {
        if (send(con.sockfd, data.c_str(), packageSize, 0) == packageSize) { //use original size
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```